# How can I display .svg url as an image in ios app

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting .svg urls from server. how can I display it as image in my app. I tried to display it in UIWebView but I can't resize the content image. I am using this code

```
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg")!)
    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
    webView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
```

what is my issue.

Answer (score 2):

> The solution is to correct the web view's scroll view scale properties to fit its bounds.

http://yberdnikov.github.io/2014/06/18/uiwebview-and-svg-images-scaling/

So in swift, you would do something like this:

```
import UIKit

// make sure to include the UIWebViewDelegate protocol
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView : UIWebView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg")!)

        // don't forget to set the webView's delegate to self
        webView?.delegate = self

        // disable scrolling
        webView?.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

        webView?.scalesPageToFit = true
        webView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        webView?.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)

        // set webView's background color to clear, sometimes a black line appears at the bottom since the svg doesn't cover the entire view.
        webView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    // function from delegate protocol
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        let contentSize = webView.scrollView.contentSize
        let webViewSize = webView.bounds.size
        let scaleFactor = webViewSize.width / contentSize.width

        // scale the svg appropriately
        webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scaleFactor
        webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = scaleFactor
        webView.scrollView.zoomScale = scaleFactor
    }

}
```

Comment: Please let me know if this helps