# Draw a Bezier to a pdf using UIGraphics

Tags: swift

So the creation of `pdf` works great, then I have some bezier path in which I want to add to this pdf, I am not sure how to *add it and set it's location* inside the file :

```
  //pdf
   UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pathForPDF, CGRect.zero, nil)
   UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 1000), nil)

   // draw the bezier
   let pathFromSVGFile:UIBezierPath = // some bezier from file.

   let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()  // *obviously wrong
   context?.addPath((pathFromSVGFile?.cgPath)!)

   UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
```

This will not add the path, but I am able to add other things to this file easily, not sure how to add a path and set a location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't have to use `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`. You can just `pathFromSVGFile.stroke()`. But before you do that, make sure to set your stroke color (e.g. `UIColor.blue.setStroke()`) and set the line width (e.g. `pathFromSVGFile.lineWidth = 3`).

So,

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pathForPDF, CGRect.zero, nil)
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 1000), nil)

// draw the bezier
let pathFromSVGFile:UIBezierPath = // some bezier from file.

UIColor.blue.setStroke()
pathFromSVGFile.lineWidth = 3
pathFromSVGFile.stroke()

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
```

Comment: Thank you Rob, for some reason it draws only the first line of the file

Comment: How can I set the position to draw inside the file?

Comment: Re only first line, it may be how the SVG was converted to `UIBezierPath`. But it generally would stroke the whole bezier path, appropriately skipping gaps that result from a `moveTo` in the middle of the path. I'd suspect how the SVG was converted to a path. Just make sure it's creating a single `UIBezierPath` and moving/adding within that path. Re positioning it, you created the `CGRect` from 0, 0 to 1000, 1000. So, you'd need to see what sort of coordinates the SVG system uses and translate/scale them within that range of values yourself. It's hard to say without seeing an example of a SVG.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. Do you know of any good way to turn SVG to bezier? Other then the common libraries?

Comment: There are libraries, e.g. https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit. I don't know which is most robust or most popular. You might have to Google it. And, sadly, if you ask here on Stack Overflow, you'll get slammed because one's not supposed to ask for external sources (because they've found that it became a source of third party libraries to post ads as answers). As the S.O. docs say, questions that "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Comment: No worries, it was a fair question, IMHO, but the type of question that meets with surprisingly vigorous hostility on S.O. ;)

Comment: Well turns out that the one I used will not support open lines, so it will only draw close artworks (https://github.com/mchoe/SwiftSVG) I am not really sure how to even start modifying it to make it work. You think there is a way to directly add the SVG to the pdf file? without turning it to bezier ?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not up to speed on the various libraries. The only native programmatic support for SVG files, AFAIK, is with a web view (e.g. `let string = try! String(contentsOf: fileURL); webView.loadHTMLString(string, baseURL: nil)`) and you could, upon `webViewDidFinishLoad` then draw that to the PDF context. The challenge there is scaling appropriately (e.g. `webView.scalesPageToFit = true` or https://stackoverflow.com/a/40700101/1271826).

Comment: @Curnelious - I can't vouch for it, but for giggles and grins, I tried [JAMSVGImage](https://github.com/jmenter/JAMSVGImage) (the first library I picked at random) and I was able to render [a SVG](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg) into `UIImage` (which I then added to `UIImageView`, but you could presumably `draw` to your PDF). Yes, it's Objective-C, but worked fine from Swift.

Comment: Thanks very much, this library is not in Swift, but more importantly i am looking to create a vector pdf, not just a rendering, so i might need a more intensive solution. But thanks very much for your help !